# $\text{Sat}_{\Delta_0}(x, y)$ is $\Delta_1(\textbf{PA})$ (Kaye's book)

Tags: logic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

In Kaye's "Models of Peano Arithmetic" in chapter 9 on satisfaction a lot of effort is expanded to prove that $\text{Sat}_{\Delta_0}(x, y)$, representing truth of $\Delta_0$-sentences, is a $\Delta_1$-sentence under $\textbf{PA}$ (Theorem 9.13 in Kaye, p. 125). However, I'm unsure how this is used. Here is the theorem:

[image: Theorem 9.13 in Kaye]

Kaye then concludes:

[image: Conclusion of Theorem 9.13]

I guess the latter is a result of the properties listed in Theorem 9.13 plus induction in the metatheory on the complexity of formulas. I presume it is here that $\text{Sat}_{\Delta_0}(x, y)$ is $\Delta_1(\textbf{PA})$ is used, because somewhat earlier in the chapter Kaye has a similar strategy. He proves:

[image: Kaye Proposition 9.10]

And then mentions a similar result where instead the $\Delta_1$-ness of the formula $\text{term}(x)$ is used.

[image: Corollary of Proposition 9.10]

However, I also don't see how $\mathbb{N} \models \text{term}(m) \Leftrightarrow \textbf{PA} \models \text{term}(m)$ is used here. Furthermore, isn't it enough that $\text{term}(x)$ is $\Sigma_1$ to show this?

Comment: Incidentally, I think there's a typo in Kaye: in the "in particular" part of Theorem $9.13$, the first block of $v$s should be a block of $x$s.

Answer (score 1):

*FYI there seems to be a typo in Kaye: in the claimed ${\bf PA}$-theorem scheme of the "in particular" part, the first block of $v$s should be a block of $x$s.*

---

I don't think the $\Delta_1$-ness of $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$ is in fact used in the "in particular" passage. Rather, Theorem $9.13$ proves two things:

- a complexity bound on $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$, modulo ${\bf PA}$; and
- some nice ${\bf PA}$-provable properties of $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$.

The "in particular"  refers only to this second point; at a glance, the metatheoretic induction taking place (your guess is correct re: this) only uses the fact that ${\bf PA}$ proves enough to "break down" instances of $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$. Now granted, this second bulletpoint is **vastly** simpler than the first and, as its proof indicates, it (and consequently the "in particular" bit) could have been stated right after the Explanation of the Definition of $\mathsf{Sat_{\Delta_0}}$ in the first place.

But nonetheless the $\Delta_1$-ness of the formula $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$ (as always, modulo ${\bf PA}$) is interesting in its own right. In general, keeping track of the "provable complexity" of a formula is a useful thing to do. Note that this type of analysis is **not** subsumed by the computability-theoretic interpretation of the arithmetic hierarchy: while knowing that $\mathsf{Sat}_{\Delta_0}$ is computable is enough to conclude that it is $\Delta_1$ in the structure $\mathbb{N}$, that is not enough to conclude that it is $\Delta_1$ modulo ${\bf PA}$. So this sort of analysis is nontrivial.

---

Meanwhile, as to your last question, note that the $\Sigma_1$-ness of $\mathsf{term}(x)$ gives us $$\mathbb{N}\models\mathsf{term}(m)\implies{\bf PA}\models\mathsf{term}(m)$$ (conflating a number with its numeral, as usual). However, for the converse implication we need that $\mathsf{term}(x)$ is $\Pi_1$. For example, take $\mathsf{term}(x)$ to be "${\bf PA}$ is inconsistent" (so it ignores $x$ completely). Then - unless we grant more than mere consistency of ${\bf PA}$ - it could be the case that ${\bf PA}\models \mathsf{term}(0)$ (say) while $\mathbb{N}\not\models\mathsf{term}(0)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is much appreciated! Regarding your last paragraph: I must misunderstand something. Since $\mathbb{N} \models \text{PA}$, if $\text{PA} \models \text{term}(m)$ then $\mathbb{N} \models \text{term}(m)$ by definition, right? I don't understand what you mean with "take $\text{term}(x)$ to be '$\text{PA}$ is inconsistent' "; $\text{term}(x)$ is a given formula that expresses that $x$ codes a term in the language of arithmetic.

Comment: Also, how is $\mathbb{N} \models \text{term}(m) \Leftrightarrow \textbf{PA} \models \text{term}(m)$ used?

Comment: @Jori The assumption $\mathbb{N}\models{\bf PA}$ is a nontrivial one if we care about keeping track of the metatheory - which I think we should in this context. $\Delta_1$-ness gives us the biconditional assuming mere *consistency* of ${\bf PA}$.

Comment: And actually this will have non-meta consequences, since it will result in ${\bf PA}$-theorems of the form "If ${\bf PA}$ is consistent, then ... " instead of "If ${\bf PA}$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound, then ..."

Comment: I see your point, but I'm still confused as to the other things I mentioned. How is the equivalence used? What do you mean with take "$\text{term}(x)$ to be 'PA is inconsistent' "?

Comment: @Jori The former question will require me to think in more detail than I have time for at the moment, sadly :P. Re: the latter, I mean exactly that. If $\mathsf{term}(x)$ is the sentence "${\bf PA}$ is inconsistent" - which is fine, there's no rule saying that the free variable $x$ has to actually be important in the formula (if you really want to use it, just append "$\wedge x=x$") - then ${\bf PA}$ + $Con({\bf PA})$ is *not* enough to prove $\mathsf{term}(0)\iff {\bf PA}\vdash\mathsf{term}(0)$.

Comment: The point is that we have a $\Pi_1$ formula such that "truth=provability" for that formula's standard instances is not provable just from the assumption of consistency alone. $\Delta_1$-ness avoids this.

Comment: Oh, you mean take "PA is inconsistent" _instead_ of $\text{term}(x)$, then this is an example that shows that in general if you just want to assume consistency of PA without any soundness assumption, it is not the case that you have both direction of the equivalence? You only have this in the $\Delta_1$-case, which is why proving a formula has this complexity is significant.

Comment: @Jori Exactly, yes.